# How can I build pdflatex from source? Is Xaw needed?

Tags: pdftex, texlive, source

I am compiling latex on linuxppc64le (RHEL 8.3) with

`../configure --prefix=$HOME/contrib/latex`

and I get the build failure

```
checking for Xaw headers... no
configure: error: Sorry, you will need at least the Xaw header/library files to compile xdvik.
=== configuring in xdvik failed
make[2]: *** [Makefile:921: recurse] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/jc6044/Documents/builds/latex/tugbuild/texk'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:491: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/jc6044/Documents/builds/latex/tugbuild/texk'
make: *** [Makefile:582: all-recursive] Error 1
```

so I add the configure option

`--without-x`

but I do not see pdflatex in the resulting build.

So then it seems I can copy pdftex to pdflatex, but to make it work, I
need pdflatex.fmt, which I cannot seem to generate?

Comment: pdflatex is a symbolic link to pdftex

Comment: The pdfLaTeX format requires the pdfTeX binary (`pdflatex` is just a symlink for `pdftex` on Linux). It sounds like you make `pdftex`, so you shopuld be OK to build the format from `pdflatex.ini` (although I suspect we need to know why you are building from source).

Comment: `fmtutil-sys --all` after you have installed the binaries should make all the formats including pdflatex

Comment: Building from source as this is on a computer that I do not have root privileges for, and I cannot find pre-built packages for linuxppc64le.  I would need to install them in my user area.

Comment: fmtutil-sys gives:
$ fmtutil-sys --all
Can't locate mktexlsr.pl in @INC (@INC contains: /home/jc6044/contrib/latex/tlpkg /home/jc6044/contrib/latex/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive /home/jc6044/contrib/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0/ppc64le-linux /home/jc6044/contrib/perl-5.32.0/lib/site_perl/5.32.0 /home/jc6044/contrib/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0/ppc64le-linux /home/jc6044/contrib/perl-5.32.0/lib/5.32.0) at /home/jc6044/contrib/latex/bin/powerpc64le-unknown-linux-gnu/fmtutil line 23.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/jc6044/contrib/latex/bin/powerpc64le-unknown-linux-gnu/fmtutil line 25.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I followed the instructions at https://www.tug.org/texlive/custom-bin.html after finding binaries at http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/texlive-utah/bin/ppc64le-linux.tar.xz:

- Go the the directory under which you want texlive:

```
wget http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/texlive-utah/bin/ppc64le-linux.tar.xz
wget http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
tar xf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
perl install-tl-20201228/install-tl --custom-bin=$PWD/ppc64le-linux
```

- Select d and respond `<curdir>/tetex/2020`
- Select 1
- Finally,

```
fmtutil-sys --all
```